# PrimeFaces Extension codeScanner results in a white screen

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-extensions, zxing-js

I'm trying to replicate this example https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/codeScanner.jsf but a white screen appears, somebody can help me?

Comment: @JasperdeVries I try to test in desktop, codeScanner only work on mobile?

Comment: Any errors in your browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: No, how i can grant access to camera? I'm using chorme

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that some users experience issues with this component in the showcase when the browser decides the that the site is not secure:

[image]

This is a browser dependent issue possibly in combination with the type of SSL, or certificate PrimeFaces is using on their server. Note that this may change over time.

If this happens to you, first try upgrading your browser. If that did not help, try the component on localhost or a https server with no security issues for the browser you are using.

See also:

- https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins